# What's the origin of particulate matter (pm10, pm2 5)

Tags: climate-change, air-pollution, air-quality, particulates, pm2.5

I would like to ask about origin and inventor of particulate matter pm10, pm2.5.

Who published and defined this formulas and when.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You question is lacking detail & I suspect there may be a language translation issue. When you ask who invented pm 10 & pm 2.5 do you mean actually invented or who first had the idea for classifying particulate matter by size & used 2.4 micron & 10 microns as sizes of such matter? Also, what formulas are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to EarthScience.SE. Do you mean the origin of the particles in the atmosphere or do you mean the classification of PM10/PM2.5 (Why PM10 and not PM5?)? In the latter case, this question seems to be a duplicate of [Which particles are classified as PM2.5? How exactly is this defined?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16676/5594). In the first case, the text in the linked question might answer your question.